# frustrations over python venv and global modules

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-venv, python-3.8

I wrote a web scraping programming a couple of months ago, which I had `python -m venv venv` did a bunch of pip install, checked and doubled check with `pip list`, everything looks fine.

And today I wanna scrape again so I did my `source venv/bin/activate` checked with `pip list`, everything looks fine, and just keep having no module of this and that...

But when I deactivated it, it falls back to my global installed modules, my program runs perfectly fine. I could't believe it so i did :
`rm -rf venv` and
`python -m venv  source venv/bin/activate pip install -r requirements.txt`
everything installed, check with `pip list`, and no module of this or that.

Anyone, please tell me what's happening?
thank you!

Comment: check your python path `which python`

Comment: python3.8, i made sure I am not using 2.X, and venv is recommended by python 3.8 doc, that's why i stick with it

Answer (score 1):

To ensure what python is being used and which python is linked to current pip:

- `which python` to see where is the python executable (alternatively `which python3`, `which python3.7`, etc...)
- running `python` show the version of python
- `pip -V` shows the python to which it is linked
- use `python -m pip list` to ensure the pip is linked to the python
- `python -m site` shows were is the `site-package` located
- writing `python` and hitting `TAB` multiple times shows what pythons are available in the path (os dependent)

This is more of a way to debug which python is being used.

Comment: Actually turns out i should have remove all the venv file, and reinstall everything but recently I have found the great pipenv install and pipenv shell, life changing stuff!