# pip list after copy folder with whole venv

Tags: python-venv

Is it possible to list correctly (pip list) libraries that were installed previously after copy it from backup?
After copy the project from backup which has own venv inside this folder to new computer it doesn't show me the list correctly. In folder
venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
I see all libraries the project needs to open but pip list show me default list of my computer.

Comment: What do you mean by "correctly installed" ? Are you sure you are launching the right python (please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66209449/14476967)) ?

Comment: I mean old project I had on my old hard drive I copied whole folder to new drive and inside this folder I have all libraries I installed when I built this project for example I had there NumPy, Matplotlib etc. and I see this libraries in folder venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages but when I activate this venv and pip list I can't see that libraries

Comment: @ygorg Do You know how to implement all libraries?