# Trouble with spacy in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, nlp, spacy

I have been trying to get spacy running in Jupyter Notebooks.  I have the book "Natural Language Processing in Python and Spacy."  I reinstalled the en module (got a message saying, "linking successful") and tried this code from the book for a test

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp(u'I am flying to Frisco')
print([w.text for w in doc])
```

but got this error:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-16fb1067de06> in <module>
  1 import spacy
----> 2 nlp = spacy.load('en')
  3 doc = nlp(u'I am flying to Frisco')
  4 print([w.text for w in doc])

c:...\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py in 
load(name, **overrides)
 19     if depr_path not in (True, False, None):
 20         deprecation_warning(Warnings.W001.format(path=depr_path))
---> 21     return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
 22 
 23 

c:...\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py in 
load_model(name, **overrides)
117     elif hasattr(name, 'exists'):  # Path or Path-like to model data
118         return load_model_from_path(name, **overrides)
--> 119     raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))
120 
121 

OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a 
valid path to a data directory.
```

Frankly any help would be so much appreciated

Comment: You can check whether the python you used to download the 'en' model is the same that you are using in the jupyter notebook [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66209449/14476967). You can launch commands in jupyter by executing a cell containing `!pwd` for example.

Comment: - ygorg thank you for your help. I deleted the two python versions and did a fresh install, It did work after that.  People like you make independent learning possible! Keep it up. Also updated the path for spacy and python