# how to install longformer library from github

Tags: python, pip, nlp, package, conda

I am somehow unable to install longformer package by following the instructions from https://github.com/allenai/longformer .

```
conda create --name longformer python=3.7
conda activate longformer
conda install cudatoolkit=10.0
pip install git+https://github.com/allenai/longformer.git
```

```
import torch
from longformer.longformer import Longformer, LongformerConfig
from longformer.sliding_chunks import pad_to_window_size
from transformers import RobertaTokenizer
```

results in error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'longformer'

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: You can use the commands [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66209449/14476967) to see whether you are using the right python and the right pip.

Comment: did you figure it out @karabara, I am trying to do same now